# Angular redirect again to login page after successfully login

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, authentication, nestjs

After implementing `back-end` with `nest-js` to make a `authentication` with `mongo-db`, my implementation work fine when i try to register and login, but my problem is after login with `successful` result, refreshing page redirect me to `login` route

`cookie` result after successfully login :

```
Authentication  
expires "2022-07-29T09:48:43.000Z"
httpOnly    true
path    "/"
value   "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiI2MmUyOTUzMmQwZGVmYjA5NGFiMTU0YzMiLCJpYXQiOjE2NTkwODQ1MjMsImV4cCI6MTY1OTA4ODEyM30.QfMS3hI-Jpyj9CCSPgQfxHplTewSX95rl7lLTVSm-pg"
```

and

```
POST
    http://localhost:4200/api/auth/login
Status
201
Created
VersionHTTP/1.1
Transferred568 B (62 B size)
Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin
Request PriorityHighest
```

response:

```
_id "62e29532d0defb094ab154c3"
email   "test@gmail.com"
```

`app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    GraphQLModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HomeComponent,
    LoginModule,
    SignUpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers:
    [{
      provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
      useFactory: (httpLink: HttpLink) => {
        return {
          cache: new InMemoryCache(),
          link: httpLink.create({
            uri: '^api/graphql' //using proxy
          })
        }
      },
      deps:[HttpLink]
    }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

`auth.guard.ts`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate() {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated().pipe(
      tap((authenticated)=>{
        if(!authenticated){
          console.log('you should login')
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
      })
    )
  }
}
```

`app.component.ts`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'front-root',
  templateUrl: './front.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./front.component.css']
})
export class FrontComponent implements OnInit {
  isLoggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly router: Router
  ) {
    this.isLoggedIn$ = authService.authenticated$;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

`auth.service.ts`

```
@Injectable(
  {
    providedIn: 'root'
  }
)

export class AuthService {
  private readonly authenticated = new Subject<boolean>();
  authenticated$ = this.authenticated.asObservable();

  constructor(private readonly httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  isAuthenticated() {
    return this.httpClient.get<boolean>('api/auth/login').pipe(
      tap(() => {
        this.authenticated.next(true);
      }),
      catchError(() => of(false)));
  }
}
```

`front-routing.module.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  {
    path: 'news', loadChildren: () => import('./pages/news/news.module').then(n => n.NewsModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'teachers',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/teachers/teachers.module').then(n => n.TeachersModule),
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {path: 'not-found', component: NotFoundComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'not-found'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class FrontRoutingModule {
}
```

BTW on opening `teachers` route i get this message and error:

```
XHR GET http://localhost:4200/api/auth/login
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 4ms]

you should login
```

but this module redirect me to login page.

`proxy.conf.json``

```json
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false,
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

`angular.json`

```json
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    "browserTarget": "front-end:build:production" ,
    "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
  },
  "development": {
    "browserTarget": "front-end:build:development",
    "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscribing to your event/service, when you get your correct data, you should save the token somewhere and then use `Router` to navigate your page which I don't see in your component.

Maybe reading Angular document will help you more about this routing:

https://angular.io/guide/router